# Angular with Django development

Tags: django, angular

I've almost finished developing my frontend in Angular 2 using static json files as API mocks. Now I want to use it with my real API from Django, and I'm struggling with few issues, since it is my first Angular 2 frontend.

I've moved whole Angular project generated by Angular CLI as `frontend` directory within my Django project. Django is exposing API at `/api`, and I want to perform request to that API from Angular. In production, Angular sources will be transpiled into javascript and moved into static (i guess), but I don't know how to handle it during development.

Is it possible to run Django development server with Angular `ng serve` on the same port at the same time? If I'll run them at different ports, I will need to hardcode my API url in frontend, and enable CORS which won't be enabled in production.

What are the best practices to develop Angular with Django?

Comment: I think you don't need run ng side and Django on the same port during the development process. You can configure your angular-cli.json end configure the different environment for dev and prod. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3539

Comment: Ok, but in production there will be no URL. Just `/api/something` as all API urls will be relative. I don't wan't such differences between dev and producion...